# Pandas Dedupe: supplying self-created training data

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzy-search, python-dedupe

I'm using `pandas-dedupe` to link a dataframe with mispellings to another with record-level info. Here is a much simplified example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['cat', 'dog', 'frog', 'mouse', 'snake'], \
       'info': ['mammal', 'mammal', 'amphibian', 'mammal', 'reptile']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['caat', 'mous', 'dog', 'xfrogg', 'snak', 'xyzgiraff']})
```

I have separate training data in csv file, which looks like this:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'orig': ['caat', 'mous', 'dog'], 'correct':['cat', 'mouse', 'dog']})
```

How can I pass the labels in `df3` as the training data in my call to `pandas_dedupe.link_dataframes`? I've tried reading the `dedupe` documentation, but I'm not sure how to format `df3` so that I can pass it as training data.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create labels using pandas-dedupe rather than passing your own labels into link_dataframes.

pandas-dedupe saves settings and labels into a *_settings and *_training.json file respectively. However, I would *not* encourage to add your labels to the file since you might create a mismatch between training and settings file.